# Rails Deployed on Heroku undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass dealing with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app deployed on Heroku. It's the Twitter app given in a lot of samples. I was trying to learn how to git a Rails app deployed on Heroku. Anyway, when clicking on the `follow` button, nothing happens. I used `heroku logs` and found this to be the issue:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/user_relationships_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

The parameters passed are this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NIiiOgQ4iowSxezGmvLk3oV/vul+4ysWoFrgh/1eOAY=", "user_id"=>{"follower_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"follow"}
```

Which corresponds to this line:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id][:follower_id])
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

As requested:

```
<%= form_for current_user.user.build(:follower_id => @user.id), 
         :remote => true do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :follower_id %></div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "follow" %></div>
<% end %>

$('#follow_form').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript render(:file =>'users/_follow_form') %>");
$('#followers').replaceWith('<div id="followers"><h1><%= "Followers: #{@user.followers.count}" %></h1></div>');
```

Comment: Are you sure the lines match up correctly? Error mentions `create` method, but your posted line is a `find`…

Comment: I don't remember which tutorial exactly. And create is the method where the error occurred. The line I posted is correct and is the only line that contains any brackets.

Comment: Fair enough. Well there must be more to it than that, because if all the info you've presented is correct (and matched), it should be right. Can you post your controller in its entirety, perhaps?

Comment: This looks like it's from Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).  The line I have in my `relationships_controller.rb` file is `@user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])`, which is for the latest (3.2) version, but this may not be the case for older versions. @NSchulze, can you perhaps post your javascript files under `app/views/relationships/` and your follow/unfollow forms under `app/views/users/` (assuming I have the directory/file names correct)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm terribly sorry I bothered you with this. For whatever reason, I had two controllers named very similarly. It was using the wrong one and I didn't realize it. I switched the code and now it works. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions for how you can get more info and figure out what is going on:

1. Prove that it works locally.  This doesn't seem like a heroku specific issue yet.
2. Figure out which tutorial you got this from, as there may have been a syntax error in an example that has since been fixed or highlighted in a comment on that site. (we don't have enough info to help you yet)
3. Add some logging, print out params prior to that call.
4. Push your code as a public github repo, and link back here. Then we can look at your code and run it to see what the issue is.

Comment: It worked flawlessly locally. Making me think it was a Heroku issue, however, it was also deployed with SQLite3 locally. I believe it was the Rails tutorial mentioned above, I changed some variable names though.

Comment: This looks like it should have been a comment link to How to Ask, or another similar resource.